# create web service with 200 input parameter which is the optimized way and how?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I want to create a webs-service with 200 input parameters Using Asp.Net. previously I have managed with 100+ parameter using class objects. This time with more parameter with more datatype lengths. I prefer xml for this.

But I need expertise advise for optimized way and how. Idea about performance point of view also.

Appreciate you advise. Thanks

Comment: _"expertise advise"_ - reconsider your approach. Requiring 200 parameters is a design flaw. Anyway what is your question?

Comment: @CodeCaster will change moving forward. need to send the values from one system to another system, using webservices. which contains 200 values. what approach i can go for? pls advise

Comment: Instead of sending a bunch of parameters create a *proper hierarchy of data transfer objects*. Anything with more than 10 parameters is a serious bug, whether it is a method call or a service. Besides, web services use **documents**, not raw parameters. You'll see that your WSDL actully defines an operation that receives a *single* request document with 100 or 200 properties. What you are doing is the opposite of the WS way already

Comment: If there is absolutely no way to create a proper method right now, at least create a single DTO with all the desired properties

Comment: @panagiotis why dont we transfer via xml, any idea. But i have managed in one of my system, 100 plus values passed through  classobjects, but with 4 different class object

Comment: The comment doesn't make sense. Web Services *do* use XML. The DTOs *are* converted to XML. This XML is deserialized to objects  and parameters, and passed to your method by .NET. Why would you want to re-deserialize the request? In effect you *could* use one single string parameter (that's how the "XML parameter" would be implemented) but users of this service would be **very annoyed** - as in contract-cancellation annoyed. You'd force them (and yourself) to do what the framework *already* does for you

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos can you please suggest the solution for this approach. do you mean DTO is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have created a web service with custom class object as parameter.My custom class object which consist of 185 properties. I have exported the inputs of custom class objects to sample.xml file.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string SubmittoSOT(XXSampleObjects sampleobjects)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XXSampleObjects ));
        string filepath = Server.MapPath("File/sample.xml");
        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filepath))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, sampleobjects);
        } 
        return "1";
    }

 [Serializable]
public class XXSampleObjects 
{
    public int      param1        {get;set;}
    public int      param2  {get;set;}
    public DateTime param3  {get;set;}
    public string  param4   {get;set;}
    public decimal param5   {get;set;}
    public decimal param6   {get;set;}
    public string  param7   {get;set;}
    public decimal param8   {get;set;}//money datatype
    public int     param9  {get;set;}
 }
```